# Querying mongodb gridfs file data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

hi i am a newbie to gridfs and am able to insert a file and view the file in gridfs using the query below

```
mongofiles -d myfiles put hi.txt

db.fs.files.findOne({'filename':'hi.txt'});
```

I need to view the contents of the file(hi.txt) i tried getResources but it didnt seem to work.Am stuck here,any help will be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in nodeJS (though you didn't specifically mentioned it in your question, just tagged it), the `GridStore` object is to be used for manipulating the files:

(quoted form the [GridStore doc](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/gridfs.html))

> Opening a GridStore (a single file in GridFS) is a bit similar to opening a database. At first you need to create a GridStore object and then open it.

```js
 var gs = new mongodb.GridStore(db, filename, mode[, options])
```

> **Reading from GridStore can be done with read**

```js
 gs.read([size], callback)
```

> where
>
> - size is the length of the data to be read
> - callback is a callback function with two parameters - error object (if an error occured) and data (binary string)
>
> **Streaming from GridStore:**
>
> You can stream data as it comes from the database using stream
>
> gs.stream([autoclose=false])
>
> where
>
> - **autoclose** If true, current GridStore will be closed when EOF and ‘close’ event will be fired
>
> The function returns read stream based on this GridStore file. It supports the events `‘read’, ‘error’, ‘close’ and ‘end’`.

Also, at the quoted doc site, there are a lot of useful examples for storing file, etc...

Recommended reading:

- [A primer for GridFS using the Mongo DB driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle2.html)